# Why aren't entities of the same kind implicitly in the same entity group

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, batch-processing

Why aren't entities of the same kind implicitly in the same entity group when they don't have a parent (they are root entities)? Does that mean if I want to do for example batch operations of writing data from MySQL to HRD:

```
db.put([Person(name=person.name) for person in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM person")])
```

and I have to use transaction for this reason:

> Note: A batch call to db.put() or db.delete() may succeed for some entities but not others. If it is important that the call succeed completely or fail completely, you must use a transaction, and all affected entities must be in the same entity group.

Source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Batch_Operations

I need to create a common root parent key, which does not exists as a real entity only for the purpose of transaction?

```
parent_key = db.Key.from_path('Human', 'human')
db.put([Person(parent=parent_key, name=person.name) for person in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM person")])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entities of the same kind are not implicitly in the same entity group because it would generally give terrible performance for the majority of use cases.

While not entirely accurate, you can think of entity groups as a way to control sharding.  Entities in the same group are stored in close physical proximity (ie on the same server), allowing all entities to be operated on transactionally, but also limiting performance on that entity group.  Parent relationships within entity groups are not restricted to kind, parent entities need not be in the same kind as children.

Most of the time, entity groups would contain various entities of different kinds, which logically belong together because transactions tend to be based on the group.  For example an Account might be the parent of a bunch of Transactions, or a BlogPost might be the parent of a bunch of Comments.

Putting all entities of a Kind under the same parent would prevent them from being properly parented for other operations where they really need to be in transactions.

In your case, it's probably better not to run the operation in a transaction, and have extra code to handle failure cases.

Comment: *In your case, it's probably better not to run the operation in a transaction, and have extra code to handle failure cases.* I am looking API for put operation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#put, it does say that you can catch the exception, if some of the entities fail: *An exception will always be raised if any error occurs during the operation, even if some of the entities actually were written. If the call returns without raising an exception, then all of the entities were written successfully.* But how do you know which entities should you repeat?

Comment: @Jernej: You don't. That's why GAE docs say that your operations within transactions should be _idempotent_ (i.e. repeating the operation yields the same result).

Answer (score 1):

No, kind and parent are two different parts of the key. The full key actually consists of application id (implicitly set), namespace id, parent keys (all parent keys to the root) and name or id.

If you omit the parent then entity is the root of the entity group and is the only entity in this entity group.

In your case a batch of `Person` entities does not make one entity group, but rather every `Person` is (from standpoint of transaction) in its own entity group. So your batch put will not be atomic.

Note: entity group is a fancy name for "let's put all this entities on the same machine".

Note 2: there are now the new [Cross-Group transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Cross_Group_Transactions) which enable you to have a transaction across 5 different entity groups.

Comment: *In your case a batch of Person entities does not make one entity group, but rather every Person is (from standpoint of transaction) in its own entity group.* I reckon that every Person that is put in the HRD is in it's own transaction. But all Person entities should be under one entity group, as they all have the same parent? So if I put in batch 5 Persons, I will have 5 transactions?

Comment: First you have to explicitly use transactions if you want them. Second, from your code I dont see that `Person` has parent set.

Comment: Look at the second snippet, does not that set the parent:db.put([Person(parent=parent_key, name=person.name) for person in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM person")])

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that one. Please also not that putting entities in the same group has performance consequences: there is a limitation of 1 write/s per entity group.